# Apache Zeppelin error not runningorg.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.util.InterpreterOutputStream@518bebd6

Tags: apache-zeppelin

In my Apache Zeppelin %Spark function but python gives me this error:

python not started

python process not runningorg.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.util.InterpreterOutputStream@518bebd6

I tried in the configuration: zeppelin.python python, python3 o python -i.